# What settings need to be configured on my firewall/router to support XBOX Live connections?

Tags: xbox-360, networking

What network and firewall settings are required to connect to XBOX Live through my home network?

I had everything set up correctly and working but had to reset my router after a firmware upgrade and lost all my settings.

Oh, and I also need the settings to enable it to work as a Media extender.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the following ports are open to the XBOX.  According to the [support site](http://support.xbox.com/support/en/us/nxe/kb.aspx?category=xboxlive&ID=908874&lcid=1033) these are the ports used by XBOX Live

- TCP 80
- UDP 88
- UDP 3074
- TCP 3074
- UDP 53
- TCP 53

For Media Extender you need:

- UDP 3776
- TCP 3390
- UPnP Framework
- Media Center (on your PC) usually found at c:\windows\ehome\ehshell.exe

I don't know precisely what settings are necessary on UPnP and Media Center, but you can refer [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/mediacenter/extender/setup/default.mspx) for more settings (on XP)

Comment: If you need help with the *how* of actually opening the ports listed, I suggest you take that question to SuperUser, but here is the *what*.

Comment: I think I can manage applying those settings. Thanks.

BTW: I saw some sites suggesting I use the XBOX's IP address in the DMZ setting, is that advisable? It sounds like it might create some security risks.

Comment: I don't know if it will create a security risk, but as with most networking problems, if a something works, don't change it.  I would only recommend doing that if XBOX Live doesn't work with the ports opened.

Comment: Either manually open ports, or make the Xbox a DMZ, or preferably enable UPnP on your router. Don't combine methods. @Mechko the second part of your answer suggests combining UPnP with open ports. This would make the open ports redundant (and perhaps counterproductive).

Answer (score 1):

You may also need "[a minimum MTU setting of 1364](http://support.xbox.com/support/en/us/nxe/kb.aspx?ID=979104&lcid=1033&category=xboxlive#)" on your router.

My connection would only work intermittently without this.

Comment: Is it good enough to just set the MTU to "Auto" mode or should I manually specify a value above 1364?

Comment: Auto tends to choose the largest available MTU, so you'll probably be good with auto